# Unable to add MX records from plesk

Tags: plesk

I have a domain added from plesk 12 on 1and1 vps hosting. Now I want add MX rexords for that domain to send and receive mails via zoho mail.

Here are the steps I'm taking:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Plesk database inconsistency, here how step 2 should looks like(pay attention there is domain name after first "." char "test.tld"):

[image: plesk create MX DNS record]

You may try to repair by yourself via `plesk db repair` or contact Plesk support.